# What is technically happening in the server when you "prepare an SQL statement"? $mysqli->prepare($sql)

Tags: php, mysqli

> mysqli::prepare -- mysqli_prepare — Prepares an SQL statement for
> execution

I don't really understand when you say
"**prepare** an SQL statement", what actually is happening?

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ?");
```

Comment: You need more than what is already available at https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php and https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-prepared-statements.php ?